# Push Notification Object

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

My app receives push notifications and sometimes these notifications come with an object that has to be stored on core data.

What happens if one of these notifications with an object arrives to the application when it is not running?

How do I handle that?

thanks

Comment: Not running is ambiguos - do you mean that the app is not running in the foreground, or not running in the foreground and background?

Comment: both. Lets consider all options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have implemented method

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{}
```

It will be fired up for every notification during the sleep, when the app becomes active.

Comment: Note that this will only get called for notifications that the user actually taps (e.g. in Notification Center).

Comment: @Ivan . what about the object. Will it be there?

Comment: @omz - what do you mean by "user actually taps"?

Comment: @RubberDuck If your app is not running (in the foreground), a notification arrives, but the user ignores it and just opens your app from the home screen, you will not get the notification info.

Comment: Yes it will certainly be there. But in Apple developer guide they are saying that push notification is not reliable way to send data, main functionality of push notifications is only to notify user for something new. If you have data that you cant afford to lose, you may reconsider new architecture. For example device receives new notification, and then while handling it make new request to your server so it returns actual data.